# create virtual directory on Amazon Instance

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, elastic-beanstalk

Alright,
So I have an AMI that I use for a beanstalk app. I started with the generic amazon instance it gives you, and then mounted an EBS volume on it. I then uploaded my webapp. What I wanted to do next was have some kind of virtual directory on the site /files that is accessible via the web and points to the mount location `/mnt/Files` . I tried

`sudo ln -s /mnt/Files /home/webapp/files`

But that didn't work. I don't have access to webapp folder, so I can't really dig around.

So my question here is two fold.

1) Is there a way to configure a virtual directory like that without modifying the vm itself.

2) If there isn't a way to do it that way, how would I go about making a virtual directory? I'm not even certain that webapp contains the server files etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching in the wrong place. The place where I needed to make the symlink was in `/var/www/html`, then I could save it as an ami and then reload it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use the [.ebextensions mechanism](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-commands) to run commands at instance creation time rather than creating a custom AMI.

Something along the lines of:

```
commands:
   create_html_dir: 
   command: mkdir /var/www/html
```